# Error in building OpenCV 3.1 in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.1 in Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite, however after cmake there was always the following error:

```
/Users/cwang/Downloads/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp(503): error: identifier "_Static_assert" is undefined
detected during:
instantiation of "cv::Matx<_Tp, m, n>::Matx(_Tp, _Tp) [with _Tp=float, m=2, n=1]"
```

OpenCV 3.0 would not produce the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I get around this error by setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11` (check the advanced box if you are using the CMake GUI).

The `CV_StaticAssert` macro should expand to `static_assert` for a modern c++ compiler. See the macro for `CV_StaticAssert` in [base.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp) starting at line 275.